# Spring Boot not embedding custom script

Tags: java, spring-boot, executable-jar

I am trying to make a executable jar with spring boot.  It will be run on FreeBSD so I need to add a custom embeddedLaunchScript, but have not been able to do so.

In the projects pom.xml file I have added the executable and embeddedLaunchScript tags but when I open the jar I generate after doing run as maven install, I cannot find the script and when I try to run the application on my server it give the following error:

```
./MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-bash: ./MyApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any insight into what I am missing would be most appreciated.

Below is the relevant portion of my pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.company.project.MyApplication</mainClass>
          <executable>true</executable>
          <embeddedLaunchScript>myApp-launch-script.sh</embeddedLaunchScript>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this error was due to the fact that my script had windows line endings, not that the script was missing.

Removing the line endings solved the issue.